# Reading a file on the local machine with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript. What I am trying to do is:
write a script which will read an php or txt file, take the info (a number), and replace it on the page like a banner. It will be something like a rating, and the number of this rating will be taking on the local machine.

I need some script which will work with most of browsers.

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: JavaScript is not the ideal candidate for this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Only Internet Explorer supports this via ActiveXObject. You can access the file system using ActiveXObject and then read the file.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx

Sample Code:

```
function ReadFiles()
{
   var fso, f1, ts, s;
   var ForReading = 1;
   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   f1 = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", true);
   // Write a line.
   Response.Write("Writing file <br>");
   f1.WriteLine("Hello World");
   f1.WriteBlankLines(1);
   f1.Close();
   // Read the contents of the file.
   Response.Write("Reading file <br>");
   ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", ForReading);
   s = ts.ReadLine();
   Response.Write("File contents = '" + s + "'");
   ts.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And what if the number will be taken on the server?

Comment: JavaScript is only for Client-Side my friend !!

Comment: Thanks for your help. if only IE will work with it, what is better to use? I need some script which will work the IE, Chrome, Opera etc.

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, you need to read a numeric value and display it on the webpage. Try to fetch the number using Ajax or whatever server side technology you are using i.e. php / java and then incorporate the same into your webpage.